# matlab vector indexing with nested slices

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have data coming from different experiments, stacked in columns. One of these columns is an experiment number, another column is data I should analyse.

From data to analysis I need to take only part, and for single experiment I know an index where I should start and where I should finish. I want to create one logical vector if my data is for analysis or not.

As an example:

```
a = [8 8 8 6 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 5 5 5 5 8 8 ]';
b = [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3]';
```

are vectors `a` with data I need, `b` is the experiment number. 
I need to finish with:

```
logicalINeed = [0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 ];
dataFroAnalysis = a(logicalINeed==1)'
```

which gives an output:

```
dataFroAnalysis =

     6     6     6     5     5     5     5
```

I know index for each experiment but not full stacked column:

```
b2_lower = 3; % index where analysis should start
b2_upper = 5; % index where analysis should end
b3_lower = 4;
b3_upper = 7;
```

I thought to simply create zeros and change to one if it is in range

```
c = zeros([length(a),1]);
c(b==2(b2_lower:b2_upper)) = 1;
c(b==3(b3_lower:b3_upper)) = 1;
```

Obviously this does not work as it should. I try to implement for loop but finish with many counter and no efficiency at all. The original data is more than 100.000 entries with 500 hundred different experiments.

is there a simple indexing way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look at how you're creating those `a` and `b` vectors in the first place - is there nothing you can do at an earlier stage to make later processing easier? Where do you get the index values from in the first place?

Assuming that you cannot alter your data format, but also that the numbers in `b` are in continuous blocks:

```
[c, ia, ic ] = unique(b);
```

By default `ia` contains the first location of each unique value (i.e. the start of each experiment set). Therefore, you can work out an offset for your index values:

```
boffset = ia-1;
```

Where `boffest(n)` is the offset for the index relating to experiment `c(n)`.

Depending on how you have the index values stored, you can then use that offset to work out where those values are in the full column.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I totally understand what you are asking, but here are a few things that might help.

First, you can do indexing with logical expressions, like this:

```
dataFroAnalysis = a(a~=8)

dataFroAnalysis =

     6     6     6     5     5     5     5
```

Second, you might find the "find" command useful, along with "union" or "intersect":

```
index_where_5 = find(a==5);
index_where_6 = find(a==6);

index_where_5_or_6 = union(index_where_6, index_where_5);

dataFroAnalysis = a(index_where_5_or_6)

dataFroAnalysis =

     6     6     6     5     5     5     5
```

Comment: Thanks. I gave vector a only for example purpose and only for simplicity it has this three values. My aim is to get logical vector based only on values on vector b and indexes bn_lower, bn_upper. In the original problem I can't index on values of a.